# How to check if Worker Role is running in Azure Emulator

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I was wondering if there was a way to check if the worker role was running inside the emulator. I have 2 worker roles and one of them shouldn't run locally, but since they are both in the same Azure Cloud Project, they both run.

One way around it is to use `#if !DEBUG` and surround all the code inside the main loop, but it feels wrong.

Is there something like ASP.Net's `Request.IsLocal`?

**Vote To Reopen**: While I have no doubt that this question is a duplicate in the strictest sense of the meaning, the question linked from here uses only the old terminology and would never have been found by a person searching today for the Windows Azure terms and namings that are currently used by the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to check it via `RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated`. For more information have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915340/how-to-detect-that-azure-application-is-running-in-development-fabric). According to the documentation it will return

> true, if the role instance is running in the compute emulator; otherwise, false.

Comment: Rather than posting an answer with a link to another SO question's answer, you should have voted to close this question as a duplicate, referencing the other question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @DavidMakogon. Will remember that the next time.